# GET Taxonomy ID

Tags: taxonomy, terms, id

I have this line where "5" is the taxonomy ID.

`<?php echo function xyz (5,'product_cat'); ?>`

How can I change this to make it auto recognize always the taxonomy ID of the current page?

Tried with no success this:

`<?php echo function xyz (get_term_by('id','','product_cat);,'product_cat'); ?>`

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on a taxonomy term archive page, you can access the current ID via `get_queried_object_id()`:

```
echo function xyz( get_queried_object_id(), 'product_cat' );
```

You can also access the whole term object with `get_queried_object()`:

```
$this_term = get_queried_object();
echo $this_term->term_id;
echo $this_term->name;
echo $this_term->description;
echo $this_term->taxonomy;
echo $this_term->parent;
echo $this_term->count;
```